# I need help solving this indefinite integrals problem?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am doing indefinite integrals homework, and this problem popped up. I hate to post on here without any personal insight on the problem, but I really have no idea on how to approach this.I do not know what to do with the information given. Any insight on how to solve the problem is what I am looking for, not specifically an answer. Thanks for all the help in advance. 
$$$$
$$$$
Kaitlyn drops a stone into a well. Approximately $4.61$sec later, she hears the splash made by the impact of the stone in the water. How deep is the well? (The speed of sound is approximately $1128$ ft./sec. Round your answer to the nearest foot.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use physics to solve this actually:

The speed of sound is $$1128\ \text{ft/sec}$$

And the total time it took to travel the height of the well is $4.61$ seconds.

Now:

$$x(t) = -16(t_1)^2 + h_0 = 0$$

$$h_0 = 1128*t_2$$

And $$t_1 + t_2 = 4.61$$

So,

$$t_1  = \sqrt{\frac{h_0}{16}}$$

$$t_2 = \frac{h_0}{1128}$$

So, we have that:

$$\sqrt{\frac{h_0}{16}} + \frac{h_0}{1128} = 4.61$$

Solving,

we find that $h_0 = 301.00 = 301\ \text{feet}$

hope this helped.

Comment: I put in 5,200 feet (rounded), and it wasn't correct. I think that would be the time it took if it hit the ground and then 4.61 seconds later you heard it. Whereas the question is saying in 4.61 seconds the stone managed to hit the ground and the sound reached the person...

Comment: @Kenshin my math was completely wrong

Comment: @Kenshin I'm very sorry I'll fix my work.

Comment: No problem, and thanks!

Comment: It has, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kenshin was this is the correct answer (sorry I'm rusty on physics)

Comment: hmm really? I'll check that now..

Comment: It wasn't. I put 545. And @ChrisK's answer of 303 was wrong too. Hmmm..

Comment: @ChrisK ohh I forget thanks. I'll fix now. Maybe I'll get a different answer and Kenshin you can try that one

Comment: @Kenshin try this answer

Comment: This is my last attempt at the question, so Let's hope it's correct haha.

Comment: @Kenshin oh no, I hope this is right

Comment: I put 921 and it wasn't right either.

Comment: @VarunIyer, it is the other way. You want $32/2 =16$.

Comment: @Kenshin screwed up the answer again... ughh why sorry

Comment: It's cool, I'm more worried on knowing how to answer the question on an exam than the homework, so no big deal. Just now I won't be able to see the answer. But, your answer has given me more insight in how to solve it, thanks!

Comment: @Kenshin was this your answer? It seems that Chris's answer was a little off of mine. **EDIT** wait does this mean you'll never know what the answer is?

Comment: @VarunIyer, mine was slightly different because I used $9.8 m/s^2$ and then converted. Of course, $9.806$ is a better estimate. I chalk this up to rounding. I didn't carry some decimals forward.

Comment: @ChrisK I understand. I hope this was the answer though, since I screwed up like 3 times already

Comment: I can't enter it again so I won't know until after the due date (tonight at midnight) so, I'll update you all if it is or isn't by then. Thanks for taking time to do this though!

Comment: Annnnnd the answer was......... 302.

Comment: must be rounding lol

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

The total time between dropping the stone and hearing the splash can be broken down into two parts:

- The time it takes for the stone to hit the water after being released from your hand ($t_1$)
- The time it takes for the sound of the splash to reach your ear ($t_2$)

You can write down an equation in terms of the height of the well, $h$, for each part, in terms of the time consumed on each part.  You can write an equation for the known total time, $T$, in terms of the individual times.

Three equations, three unknowns ($t_1, t_2, h$).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can come up with with this info.

Answer (score 1):

So, we know that $9.8\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot (\Delta(t_{1}))^2 = v_{sound}\cdot \Delta(t_{2})$ and $\Delta(t_{1}) + \Delta(t_{2}) = 4.61$.

So, $$\frac{4.9}{v_{sound}}\cdot\Delta(t_{1})^2+\Delta(t_{1}) - 4.61 = 0.$$

So, $\Delta(t_{1}) = -\frac{v_{sound}}{9.8} + \frac{\sqrt{1+19.6\cdot 4.61/v_{sound}}}{9.8/v_{sound}} = 4.34 s$, where $v_{sound} = 344 m/s$.

So, $h = \Delta(t_{2})\cdot (344 m/s) = (4.61-4.34 s)\cdot (344 m/s) = 92.4 m$. Now, this is equivalent to $303$ feet (if you dare not use SI).